# NSInvalidArgumentException while adding buttons to ActionSheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, uiactionsheet

I'm trying to create an actionsheet that will contain the list of twitter account but I'm getting this exception during creation of the button.

```
NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
```

This is the code of some important methods

//SocialNetworking.m file

```
- (BOOL)loginWithTwitterCompletionBlock:(UIView *)sender :(void (^)(User *,ACAccount *selAccount, NSError *))completionBlock
{
    ACAccountStore *store = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *twitterType = [store accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
    [store requestAccessToAccountsWithType:twitterType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        NSArray *twitterAccounts = [store accountsWithAccountType:twitterType];

        if(twitterAccounts == nil || [twitterAccounts count] == 0) {
            NSMutableDictionary* details = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            [details setValue:@"Account unavailable" forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
            NSError *error=[NSError errorWithDomain:@"authentication" code:10 userInfo:details];

            completionBlock(nil,nil, error);

        } else {

                if (granted && !error)
                    {
                        twitterAccountsArray = [store accountsWithAccountType:twitterType];

                        if ([twitterAccountsArray count] > 1)
                        {

                            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                [self accountListActionSheetDynamic:twitterAccountsArray Sender:sender];
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            selectedAccount = [twitterAccounts objectAtIndex:0];
                        }
                    }
NSURL *userDetailsURL=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json"];
//Getting the exception in this line below
                NSDictionary *params = @{@"screen_name" : selectedAccount.username,
                                         @"entities" : @"0"};

            TWRequest *request = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:userDetailsURL parameters:params requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];
            [request setAccount:selectedAccount];
            [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
             {
                if (responseData)
                {
                    NSError *error = nil;
                    NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];


                User *socialUser=[[User alloc] init];

                socialUser.twitterName=[responseDict valueForKey:@"name"];
                socialUser.twitterUserName=selectedAccount.username;
                socialUser.twitterProfileId = [responseDict valueForKey:@"id_str"];
                socialUser.twitterProfileImageURLString=[responseDict valueForKey:@"profile_image_url"];
                socialUser.twitterProfileBackgroundURLString=[responseDict valueForKey:@"profile_background_image_url"];


                completionBlock(socialUser,selectedAccount, nil);
            }

            else
                {
                completionBlock(nil,nil, error);
                }
        }];

}

//Action sheet For Multiple TwitterAccounts
- (void)accountListActionSheetDynamic:(NSArray *) accounts Sender:(UIView*) senderView {

    UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                            initWithTitle:@"Choose a Twitter Account"
                            delegate:self
                            cancelButtonTitle:nil
                            destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                            otherButtonTitles:nil];

    for(int i=0;i<accounts.count;i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"i=%d,AccountName:%@",i,[[accounts objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"username"]);
        [sheet addButtonWithTitle:[[accounts objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"username"]]; 
    }
    [sheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
    sheet.cancelButtonIndex = sheet.numberOfButtons-1;

    [sheet showFromRect:senderView.bounds inView:senderView animated:YES];

}


-(void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {

     for(int i=0;i<twitterAccountsArray.count;i++)
        {
            if([[actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex] caseInsensitiveCompare:[[twitterAccountsArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"username"]]==NSOrderedSame)
            {
                selectedAccount = [twitterAccountsArray objectAtIndex:i];

                return;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

The log does print `i=0, AccountName:twitterusername1` and crashes with the exception mentioned above. In my .h file I've set the `UIActionSheetDelegate`.

Any suggestion whats causing this exception? I'm currently using Xcode 5 and running in simulation iOS 7.

**EDIT: I was able to solve the initial issue by using dispatch_sync instead of dispatch_async. But now I'm getting the same exception at NSDictionary *params line, because the actionsheet doesnt appear until the whole code completes, is there any way to show the actionsheet before the executions moves to this line as the value of selectedAccount is not set yet**

Comment: Place an exception breakpoint to see exactly which line the exception is coming from

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace:

```
[accounts objectAtIndex:i]
```

with a previously declared  (in this loop) variable, for example -

```
NSString *name=[accounts objectAtIndex:i]
```